# matlab: send function's values to other function

Tags: matlab, session, user-interface

I have two GUI-s.

the first GUI is named: GUI1, there the user inserts three values.

then the user has a button 'Submit', so I want these values to be sent to other function (GUI2) every time he presses it.

my function GUI2.m gets three elements:

```
function GUI2(x,y,r)
   .
   .
   .
end
```

and this is the first GUI:

```
function [E] = GUI1()
    num_of_columns = 3;


    E = [];  % In case the user closes the GUI.
    S.fh = figure('units','pixels',...
          'position',[500 500 850 100],...
          'menubar','none',...
          'name','Number Of Columns',...              
          'numbertitle','off',...
          'resize','off');
    num = 0;
    for i = 1:num_of_columns
        S.ed(i) = uicontrol('style','edit',...
             'units','pix',...
            'position',[num 60 100 30],...
            'string','');
        num = num + 500/num_of_columns;
        uicontrol(S.ed(1))  % Make the editbox active.
     end

     S.pb = uicontrol('style','pushbutton',...
             'units','pix',...
            'position',[290 20 180 30],...
            'string','Submit',...
            'callback',{@pb_call});

     uiwait(S.fh)  % Prevent all other processes from starting until closed.

     function [] = pb_call(varargin)
         % Callback for the pushbutton.
         E = get(S.ed(:),'string');
         E{1} = str2num(E{1});
         E{2} = str2num(E{2});
         E{3} = str2num(E{3});
```

**In this line I want to send E{1}, E{2} and E{3} to GUI2**

```
     end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about:

```
GUI2(E{1},E{2},E{3})
```